# Get parent with only relative child elements in many to many Entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have these models:

```
public class Term
{
    public int TermId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubForm> SubForms { get; set; }
}
public class Form
{
    public int SubFormId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubForm> SubForms{ get; set; }
}
public class SubForm
{
    public int SubFormId { get; set; }
    public virtual int FormId {get; set; }
    public virtual Form Form {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Term> Terms { get; set; }
}
```

So the relationship here is `Form` has many `SubForm` while `SubForm` and `Term` are a many to many.

Now what I want is all forms and its subform that are related to a specific term.

This is the code I have right now:

```
public IList<Form> GetFormsInTerm(int termId)
{
    var forms =
        termsRepository.GetForms().Where(f => f.SubForms.Any(sf => sf.Terms.Any(t => t.TermId == termId))).ToList();

    return forms;
}
```

But for some reason, if 1 of like 5 subforms is part of a term, this code returns that parent form with ALL 5 subforms. Is there a way to just get the parent and just that subform?

Comment: shouldnt you just get subforms here ? since forms dont have direct relationship with term ? you could get all the subforms for the term and then get all the forms associated with the selected subform.

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your question instead of using GetForms you can use Getsubforms then it will be like this,

```
 var subforms =
            termsRepository.GetSubForms().Where(sf => sf.Terms.
Any(t => t.TermId == termId)).ToList();
```

this will return all `Subforms` which are related to the `term`, And then you can use those loaded `SubForms` to get their parent `Forms` .
But I don't know your requirement is fulfilled with this.

Comment: Is there a way I can massage this into the format I want from the IQueryable level rather than looping in memory? Format is forms -> subforms